# Cannot load underlying module for 'Lottie' in a mult-iproject workspace

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I'm following this tutorial of [clean swift](https://medium.com/swift2go/clean-architecture-for-massivetobe-mobile-apps-bf8e44a98b37)
But now I'm facing issues working with cocoapods. In summary I have a workspace created after run `pod init` and then I added 3 projects: presentation layer, domain layer and data layer.

As you can see in the pictures, the RadarAir-15 is the original project(before run `pod init`).

[image] [image]

Podfile

```
platform :ios, '13.6'    
workspace 'RadarAIR-15'

target 'RadarAIR-15' do
  xcodeproj 'RadarAIR-15.xcodeproj'
  
end
target 'PresentationRadarAir' do
  xcodeproj 'PresentationRadarAir/PresentationRadarAir.xcodeproj'
  pod 'lottie-ios'
end
```

And everything seems works fine until I want to add a Pod only for the presentation layer, in this case i want to use Lottie.
But I'm getting this error:

```
<unknown>:0: error: cannot load underlying module for 'Lottie'
```

And i can't user IBDesignable neither.
[image]

## UPDATE

I make it work adding the dependency to the pod in the main target: RadarAIR-15

```
target 'RadarAIR-15' do
    project 'RadarAIR-15'
    pod 'lottie-ios'
end
target 'PresentationRadarAir' do
#    use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
    project 'PresentationRadarAir/PresentationRadarAir'
    pod 'lottie-ios'
end
```

This is just a workarround because the storyboard(xib) still has the same error and I want to avoid add the dependency to the main target. But at least lottie is working by code.
**Is there a way to get rid of this  storyboard(xib) error?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I had to add `use_frameworks! :linkage => :static` and all my problems are gone :)

```
platform :ios, '13.6'

workspace 'RadarAIR-15'

target 'RadarAIR-15' do
     project 'RadarAIR-15'
end
target 'PresentationRadarAir' do
    use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
    project 'PresentationRadarAir/PresentationRadarAir'
    pod 'lottie-ios'
    pod 'Hero'
    pod 'MaterialComponents'

end
target 'DataRadarAir' do
    use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
    project 'DataRadarAir/DataRadarAir'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
end
```